# Can't include header in `$http` angular

Tags: angularjs

I got a token from backend which I saved it in `$sessionStorage` and I need to include that along with `$http` request that I call. I tried include it directly but when I checked it from backend, it's not there.

```
function _selectGender($sessionStorage, gender) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: config.apiURL + '/auth/gender',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': $sessionStorage.token
            },
            data: {
                gender: gender
            }
        }).then(updateCompleted).catch(updateFailed);
    }
```

I also tried with interceptor which it's not working as well.

```
requestInterceptor.inject = ['$sessionStorage'];
function requestInterceptor($sessionStorage){
    return {
        'request': function(config){
            if ($sessionStorage.token) config.headers['authorization'] = $sessionStorage.token;
            return config;
        }
    }
}
```

Shoot me some idea how to tackle this. :D

Edit#1: It's likely possible to be preflight error

Comment: `console.log($sessionStorage.token)` inside the function, just before return and check the value

Comment: Is config.apiURL and hosted url same?

Comment: @SyamPillai yep, token is there. I tried console.log it out before return it. It's still there when the view load. But somehow disappear when I called an api.

Comment: @NitishKumar yep, it's :D

Comment: try one hack. I'm not sure whether this will resolve our issue.
do
`var token = $sessionStorage.token`
and inside the api call

`headers: {
                'Authorization': token
            }`

Comment: @SyamPillai tested with that it's still not showing

Comment: So there is CROS issue.. So it will not work.. U need CROS enable on api server side

Comment: @NitishKumar i think i enable everything in order to make it work, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS` `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization` `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Etag`

Comment: @thestrayed Does your token start with a type? For example "Bearer" or "Basic"? If not, it is possible it is being stripped by your API as invalid.

Comment: @VladimirZdenek nope, i check with the network tab. Headers are not being sent from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually because of OPTIONS headers, seem like `$http` will send a pre-request before browser send an actual request to backend. You need to handle that from the backend. Thanks @Nitish Kumar's comment.

[Read more about cors](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/)

[How to handle OPTIONS](https://gist.github.com/cuppster/2344435)